# Django Form Validation

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible to add form errors (not a field specific errors) to a form that is already validated (form.is_valid() is already called and the result is True)?

I have additional validation logic (with database requests) which I prefer to execute after standard form validation is passed, but it will be better to associate new errors with form

Or maybe I have to call this additional validation within clear() form function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check it in the clean method of the form after all, but check existing errors before.
Like that..

```
clean(self):
    ...
    ...
    if not self._errors:
        # your extra check
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is validation based on database requests, then it shound as [model validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

Comment: I don't have a model involved in these database requests, it's a raw sql that call one database function. And the result can indicate incorrect data in form, that's why I want to associate errors with form